# indexedDb unable to create object store

Tags: indexeddb

I have created a sample application to create the indexeddb which works till yesterday, but not sure what went wrong the store is not getting created. Can some one help. Here is the fiddle for the same. Also I have created one method to delete the data from the store which is also not working

https://jsfiddle.net/ojm10u4k/

```js
var dbName = "bmiDb1";
var database;
var lookupType = [];
var dbVersion = 0;
var storeData = [{
  LookupTypeId: 2,
  Name: 'Collision',
  Description: null
}, {
  LookupTypeId: 3,
  Name: 'Grounding',
  Description: null
}]

function createObjectStore(indexDbName, storeName, keyName) {
  var objectStore;
  var version = dbVersion + 1;
  dbVersion = version;
  var request = indexedDB.open(indexDbName, dbVersion);
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    var database = event.target.result;
    if (!database.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
      objectStore = database.createObjectStore(storeName, {
        keyPath: keyName
      });
      try {
        objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
          // Store values in the newly created objectStore.
          var objectValueStore = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
          storeData.forEach(function(data) {
            objectValueStore.add(data);
          });
          database.close();
        }
        objectStore.transaction.commit();
      } catch (err) {}
    } else {}
  };
}

function createIndexDb(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = indexedDB.open(name);
    request.onsuccess = (event) => resolve(event.target.result);
    request.onerror = (event) => reject(event.target.error);
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  createIndexDb(dbName).then(db => {
    dbVersion = db.version;
    database = db;
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: modern JS note: you don't need jQuery's `ready`, just put your script in a file, and load that file with `<script src="yourscripthere.js" async defer></script>`. And if you've never seen [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer), it makes a script run only once the DOM is finalized, so that DOM queries are guaranteed to work. It's been around for over a decade now, with even IE supporting it =) (also, given that you're using promises, time to let go of those `var`. Use the not-even-modern-anymore `let` or `const` depending on whether you need mutable)

Comment: In general I am calling all the scripts after DOM was ready

Comment: OK closed the connection after the initial request as follows                                             `createIndexDb(dbName).then(db => {
    dbVersion = db.version;
    database = db;
 db.close();
  }).catch(console.error);`

Comment: Remember: don't put additional details in comments. [put them in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works after closing the connection

```
createIndexDb(dbName).then(
 db => {
   dbVersion = db.version;
   database = db;
   db.close();
 }).catch(console.error);
```